# Node server response error: process.nextTick(function(){throw err;});

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

So I have a very simple application that I'm building to practice with Mongo, Express, and Node.

I'm getting an error `process.nextTick(function(){throw err;});`

The error seems to occur when I try to use `res.json(docs)` in the success conditional during the GET request. However, I can `console.log(docs)` and see the JSON.

**Development Environment**

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Mongo 3.2
- Node 5.6

**package.json:**

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mongojs": "^2.3.0"
  }
...
```

**app.js (api):**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('catalog', ['products']);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.send('It works, indeed'); // this is working
});

app.get('/products', function(req,res){
  res.send('Products Works'); // this is displaying correctly on the page
  console.log('Fetching products');
  db.products.find(function(err,docs){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Sending Products');
      console.log('response docs', docs); // returns the correct JSON
      res.json('stuff sent'); // Throws error
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
```

I'm not sure why this is failing. I'm able to console log the JSON so know that the data is there and available in the response. Just not sure why the `res.json(docs)` doesn't work.

Comment: You don't actually ever call `res.json(docs)`, you code actually says `res.json("stuff sent")` which is of course not an "object" that can serialize to JSON and therefore throws an error. Looks like you just put that in for testing purposes and never correctly changed it.

Comment: You're correct, it was in there just for testing was actually supposed to be `res.send("string")` just to see what was breaking. Turns out had two responses which was throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the implicit callback twice

```
res.send('Products Works'); // this is displaying correctly on the page
```

and

```
res.json(docs);
```

remove either (probably the first one)

Comment: Thanks for the response, still showing the same error. I'm also seeing `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: Also make sure you are passing an object to res.json

Comment: classic async stuff. Do have a look at restify. There you are forced to either return explicitly or call next(). As a matter of good practice you can probably do it here too.

Comment: Yeah checking that out now, thanks for the resource. Digging the strict  nature. Reminds me of looking at React vs Angular 2 and reading a lot on how you get just want you need and nothing extra with frameworks.